# Propogation of *this* in nested function calls in Backbone.js

Tags: this, backbone.js

I started using backbone.js recently for a game. I used model to create Timer as follows:

```
var Timer = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'hh':00, 'mm':05, 'ss':00
    },

    initialize: function() {
    },

    countDownOnce: function() {
         // Count down the time by 1 sec
    },

    run1: function() {
        this.countDownOnce();
    }

    run2: function() {  
        setInterval(this.countDownOnce, 1000);  
    }  
});
```

The *countDownOnce* function, if called directly as in *run1*, works fine.

But if the function is passed as an argument to some built-in function, say setInterval as in the *run2* function, the value of **this** is lost.

How to propagate **this** pointer to the built-in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Backbone docs have a useful section on [binding "this"](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this).

Basically, [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) provides a couple of very useful functions, [_.bind and _.bindAll](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind), which help you more easily manage 'this's context.

```
...

initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, 'countDownOnce' //, and whatever other functions you want bound)
}),

...
```

This will make sure that no matter what context it's called from, the 'this' inside countDownOnce refers to your Timer instance.

Comment: I explored that just sometime back and was about to post here. Thanks a lot for the response :)

Comment: @rulfzid: True, but it won't bind to a function _inside_ another function. The this 'context' is lost in that case...isn't it?

Comment: @Nupul: I'm not sure what you're getting at, but you can bind your captured 'this' to inner functions explicitly if you need to, with call or apply or even _.bind.

Comment: @rulfzid: Maybe I'm confused by I guess the OP is unable to access `this.countDownOnce` in seInterval(...) inside `run2()` - so calling `_.bindAll(this, 'run2')` will still not help him address `this.countDownOnce` _inside_ setInterval which in turn is inside `run2()` - he'll have to explicitly bind it like how @aroth suggested or use `var that = this` - isn't it?

Comment: @Nupul: `_bindAll(this, 'countDownOnce')` will make the OP's example work like he wanted. The problem was that `setInterval` runs the `countDownOnce` function in the `window`'s context. What calling `_.bindAll` is doing is making sure that no matter what context you call `countDownOnce` from, its `this` refers to the Timer object

Comment: @rulfzid: Aaaaaaaaaaaah! I see :) Thanks for clarifying that...apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using [call and apply](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx).  For example:

```
run2: function() {  
    setInterval(this.countDownOnce.call, 1000, this);  
}
```

Also note that passing a closure/function reference with arguments to `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` requires some [manual hacks](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/407) to work correctly in IE.

Answer (score 1):

**this** is how javascript was designed (pun intended :)

Basically 'this' binds to the current context so if in a function/method call like this:

```
var Data = function(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

var myData = new Data("viky");
```

would refer to the name element "inside" Data (i.e., myData in this case)

Now if you had the following:

```
var Data = function(name) {

function morphName(anotherName) {
  //and if you call this like this ;)
   alert(this.name); //undefined
  }

}
```

the inner function morphName is bound to the 'current' context i.e., the outer function. In javascript everything is an object, including functions. So the outer (anonymous) function doesn't have a member called name! (makes sense?)

In order to do **that** most people use the following (by convention):

```
var Data = function(name) {

var that = this; //capture current context. Some prefer self = this;

function morphName(anotherName) {
  //then you access name like that ;)
   alert(that.name);
  }

}
```

I suggest you read about javascript closures and scopes to understand this and that :D

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer as well as the figures of speech